# Python Pandas DataFrame: KeyError 0 while iterating through the DataFrame after using the set_index and resample methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

After using the pandas set_index method and resampling the 15min dataframe to 1min dataframe I was trying to iterate through the dataframe- so the one with the 1min data time indexes. However, I got the **"KeyError: 0".**

I just tried the following simple code lines but it does not work:

```
for i in range(df.size):
    print(df[i,"value"])
```

I tried also this one:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df[i,"value"])
```

I noticed that this error only occurs when I use the set.index and the resampling method. The iteration works for the same dataframe before resampling.

Comment: You **must** provide sufficient code to reproduce exactly the same error. We have no clue what happened in "*After using the pandas set_index method and resampling the 15min dataframe to 1min*".

Comment: I found out the issue. I wrote it below but thanks

Comment: glad you did, but if you were to provide a clear reproducible example this might help future readers, as of now I doubt it will. Well crafted examples are fare more powerful than text descriptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what the issue is. After using the set_index method the dataframe has data time indexes. Using range(len
(df)) or range(df.size) is not applicable anymore.

Therefore I should use a range of time indexes to iterate through it **or** reset the date time indexes and make default indexes as index.